# How to add device information while sending request to server?

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, http-headers, security

I want to add information about the iOS and device model while sending any request to server to fetch the data from server. Can any one help me how to send some specific information to server so that server should be able to understand the request came from real iPhone/iPad device , Simulator ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UIDevice currentDevice` object to access device info:

Model:

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].model;
```

Version:

```
[UIDevice currentDevice].version;
```

Use `ASIHTTPRequest` POST to send data to server.

```
-(void)sendDataToServer{

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL_TO_YOUR_SERVER"];

        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];


        [request addPostValue:[UIDevice currentDevice].model; forKey:@"model"];
        [request addPostValue:[UIDevice currentDevice].version; forKey:@"version"];

        [request startSynchronous];

        NSError *error = [request error];
        if (!error) {
            //NO error
        }else{
            //Deal with error
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ASIHTTPRequest 1.6.x library for connectivity with server in iPhone application you can get this information in ASIHTTPRequest.m file as below

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    deviceName = [device model];
    OSName = [device systemName];
    OSVersion = [device systemVersion];     
#else
    deviceName = @"Macintosh";
    OSName = @"Mac OS X";
#endif
```